# Update Group Photo

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Contrary to the documentation on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http there is no `.Content` object available under `.Photo`.

```
 group.Photo.Content.Request().PutAsync(photoStream).Result;
```

I am looking to update the profile photo for the group and it does not seam to be available.

Comment: Did you check [this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58569252/how-can-i-set-a-team-picture-programmatically-using-microsoft-graph-api/59325136#59325136) to set a team picture programmatically using Microsoft graph API. and There is currently a [known issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#groups) with accessing group photos using application permissions.

Comment: Yes, I have checked both of those. Neither account for the lack of `.Content` on the Photo object.

Comment: Yes there is an issue with application permissions, but how can you call it with delegated permissions ? I don't understand how you can "connect" as the group itself.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working for me. Can you please try similar way.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
            var stream = await graphClient.Groups["groupId"].Photo.Content
                .Request()
                .GetAsync();
```

I have installed Microsoft.Graph Nuget version 3.4.0.